# Angular + HighCharts "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined ('xxxx') " but showing correct info

Tags: angular, highcharts, observable, subscribe, angular-highcharts

I have a dashboard with charts (Highcharts) in Angular. I can access to the data base with a PHP file, but I am getting an error when I inspect the result.
If I return a result in stocks() accessing to an Array, the data shows a chart correctly but with the following error after inspect:

[Angular error  showing chart correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceOmz.png)

If I return a result in stocks() not accessing to an Array there are no errors, but no info in the final chart

I would like to get chart with correct info but without the error of the image.

This is the interface:

```
export class Aeropuerto {
    name: string;
    data?: [];
    color?: string;
    visible: string;
}
```

Here is component.ts

```
stockChart  = [];

constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService,private http:HttpClient ){}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.stockChart = this.stocks();
  };


  stocks() {
    return[
      
      this.getStock()[0].xxx //in this way shows chart with correct info but I get the error in the image.
                             //xxx can be changed for any value and the chart shows correct data
      
    //**this.getStock()    in this way show chart without info, and I get no error**
    ]
  }
  getStock(){
    return this.dashboardService.stockCharts().subscribe(
          stockChart => {
           this.stockChart = stockChart; 
          }
    )         
  }
```

And service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DashboardService {
  apiURL = `http://phpFile.php`;



  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  stockCharts(): Observable<Aeropuerto[]> {
    return this.http.get<Aeropuerto[]>(this.apiURL);
  }
```

And finally the html where the chart template (stock) get the data:

```
<app-widget-stock  [data]="stockChart"></app-widget-stock>
```

Edit: you can see the error in console  in the following  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvbzyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.ts)

Comment: I try to recreated your case [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-a-service-4mzkwf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), could you add more details and explain? I see error like yours but not understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianHajdus  and sorry for the delay, but I finally made a  reply of my code in the following [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvbzyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.ts) . If you check the console in the browser you will see the error. You can find the code in src/app/modules/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts